# How can I troubleshoot a Rockbox Utility installation?

Tags: troubleshooting, sansa, rockbox

I'm trying to install ***Rockbox*** on my **sansa e260 v2** because it's no longer working properly and I thought I might as well try Rockbox before chucking it out.

The problem is that I can charge it fully, but then it shuts down after some 10 minutes or so... Then it won't even open at all until I plug it back into the computer. The "low battery" message doesn't even show, it just looks dead.

Anyways, I got *Rockbox Utility* and double clicked. It opens up and I get this message:
*Configuration error: Your configuration is invalid. This is most likely due to a changed device path. The configuration dialog will now open to allow you to correct the problem.*
I click *OK*.
I click *Autodetect*.
I get this message:
*Fatal error: Unless you changed this installation will fail!*

I don't understand this message at all! What does it mean? I thought maybe it had something to do with the USB mode.. Problem is, I can't find where to change USB mode on my player. I went through all the settings but I still can't find it. I'm not even sure this is really the problem.

So my question is, what do I do next?

BTW: My computer runs **Ubuntu 10.04 LTS - the Lucid Lynx**
but I have a virtual machine with Windows 7 if that can be any help..

**edit** I think I can indicate to Rockbox Utility where my device is in the filesystem by using the browse button, effectively replacing the autodetect function, but I don't know where to find this information. I looked in the /media and /media/external folders but there's nothing in there. I can transfer songs fine through Rhythmbox, but I don't know where Rhythmbox found it..

I don't know if this can be any help:
->lsusb

->Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0781:7422 SanDisk Corp. Sansa E200 series v2 (mtp)

Notice it says MTP. I tried changing to MSC on the device, but I never found out how. I'm supposed to have a "USB Mode" option under "Settings", but I don't. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find it under `/media` after changing it from [MTP to MSC](http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/207).

Comment: @digitxp Thanks for the link. I have looked under "Settings" but the "USB Mode" option is nowhere to be found!

Comment: @Shawn I'm clueless. Anything even close to 'USB'?

Comment: @digitxp Nope: Here's every single option in settings menu: Music Options, Radio Options, Slideshow Options, Backlight, Language, Date & Time, Brightness, Volume, Reset All (tried that), Info, Auto Shut-Off, Format (tried that one too), Record Button, Press and Hold.

Comment: Apart from the Settings menu, I have these other menus: Music, FM Radio, Photo, Voice, Video.

Comment: Could be that your model doesn't support MSC. Unfortunately, now is the time to toss.

Comment: An answer from the Rockbox forums which solved everything. I had to turn the player on, put it on hold, press and hold |<<, plug the player into my computer, and once it's fully connected, release |<<. This procedure connected the player in MSC Mode

Comment: @Shawn I never heard of that, could you forward the link to that forum for my reference?

Comment: @digitxp : http://forums.rockbox.org/index.php/topic,27083.0.html sorry the late response